# Creating .dll files and compiling C++ code using Rcpp on Windows

Tags: c++, r, windows, powershell, rcpp

I am having a really hard time trying to make Rcpp work on my Windows. I downloaded Rtools and I have changed the path to

> c:\Rtools\bin;c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;c:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\x64;[others]

I have then taken a really simple c++ file (new.cpp) that goes like this

```
include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int timesTwo(int x) {
return x * 2;
}
```

I then go on the Powershell and as suggested on Seamless R and C++
Integration with Rcpp by D. Eddelbuettel (Chap. 2) I try to compile the code

```
PS C:\Users\RXD308\pgmcpp> PKG_CXXFLAGS='Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::CxxFlags()''\ PKG_LIBS='Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::LdFlags()''\ RCMD SHLIB new.cpp
```

Obtaining the error

```
An expression was expected after '('.
At line:1 char:43
+ PKG_CXXFLAGS='Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::CxxFlags( <<<< )''\ PKG_LIBS='Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::LdFlags()''\ RCMD SHLIB new.cpp
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedExpression
```

Two last things

- I have MinGW up and working on my computer (g++ 4.6)
- I think I have a major problem with the R command in the powershell. In facts, as I access the powershell and I type "R --version" I obtain this error

  ```
  Invoke-History : Cannot locate history for commandline --version.
  At line:1 char:2
  + R <<<<  --version
  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (--version:String) [Invoke-History],     ArgumentException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeHistoryNoHistoryForCommandline,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeHistoryCommand
  ```

Answer (score 2):

That is a shell error:

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS='Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::CxxFlags()''
PKG_LIBS='Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::LdFlags()''
RCMD SHLIB new.cpp
```

as you have single ticks inside single ticks.  Look more carefully at page 24 and see the difference between backward-facing ticks and forward-facing ticks.  Backward implies execution.

When working through this, you can avoid these second level of indirection by just executing something like `Rcpp::LdFlags()` in your R session and the just copy the resulting string over into Makevars.

This will help you compile your code, which is the first order of business.

For creating distributable Makevars, you can then look more carefully at published solutions.

*Edit:* Make sure you can walk before you run. Start with something like this

```
C:\>R CMD config CXXFLAGS
-O2 -Wall -mtune=core2

C:\>
```

and then get towards `Rscript` invoking Rcpp functions as shown.  Maybe you have powershell issues; I just did this in `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Corrected the ticks but still obtaining the error      

    The term 'PKG_CXXFLAGS=Rscript' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
    Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:22
+ PKG_CXXFLAGS=`Rscript <<<<  -e 'Rcpp:::CxxFlags()'`\ PKG_LIBS=`Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::LdFlags()'`\ RCMD SHLIB new.cpp
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PKG_CXXFLAGS=Rscript:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: It seems that a lot of problems were caused by the powershell. In facts I managed to run the

    R CMD config CXXFLAGS -O2 -Wall -mtune=core2

But writing again the line

    PKG_CXXFLAGS='Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::CxxFlags()''\ PKG_LIBS='Rscript -e etc.

It seems that PKG_CXXFLAGS is not recognised as a command. Is the command that I am using appropriate for the windows syntax?

Comment: The uppercase stuff is not a command but an environment variable passed to make. This is all very standard and explained in many places.

Comment: Would you give me a link where I can find clear instructions on how to use the PKG_CXXFLAGS and PKG_LIBS commands on Windows? I tried to use them as an argument to "make" but it failed as well. I am not very used to run command line instructions.

Comment: I went on the "R extensions" manual and it suggests to add the flags to the makevars file. I did a search and the only makevars file I have is in RcppEigen/skeleton. I then tried to add to the file the following lines

    `-I PKG_CXXFLAGS=`Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::CxxFlags()'`

   `-L PKG_LIBS=`Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::LdFlags()'``

But nothing really changed when running the command R CMD SHLIB. I still obtain "error:include does not name a type"